# How do you expose CSV data to the client in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm just learning Meteor, and I'm fiddling with something very simple to understand how the framework works.  I load a CSV file with country names / country ids that I want to use in a SelectBox on the client.

I installed baby-parse

```
meteor add harrison:babyparse
```

I then use

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  parsed = Baby.parse(Assets.getText('geo.csv'));
  Countries = parsed.data;
});
```

How can I expose the Countries data to the client?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you'd be better off populating a Mongo collection with the country data.

If you really want to just access a server method from the client, you can call a meteor method on startup from the client and set the result of that to a session variable. For example:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Meteor.call('getCountryData', function(err, res){
    if (res){
      Session.set('CountryData', res)
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.methods({
    'getCountryData':function(){
      parsed = Baby.parse(Assets.getText('geo.csv'));
      Countries = parsed.data;
      return Countries;
    }
  });
}
```

Then use `Session.get("CountryData")` wherever needed on the client.

Again, highly recommend populating a collection in your database and then publishing/subscribing data to the client instead of this approach. Here's a good primer on the basics of MongoDB w/ Meteor: http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/databases-part-1/. Chapter 11 (Publish & Subscribe) is what you want to look at after understanding the basics.

Comment: I put your code inside Meteor.startup(function() { });  in a file in the lib directory.  When I try to call CountryData from the browser console, I get:  Uncaught ReferenceError: CountryData is not defined(…)

Comment: Did you call `Session.get('CountryData')` or just CountryData?

Comment: One last thought:  To make your answer complete, how do add the Countries Data to a Mongo Collection (which you mention as the more sensible approach)?

Comment: You'll want to mongoimport the csv into your localhost db and then define a Countries collection in your lib. Added a link to a tutorial on setting this up.

Comment: Thanks again.  I just purchased the book.  I've rarely seen a tech book with so many 5 star reviews, so the link in your answer seems golden.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108432/discussion-between-kartikshastri-and-hexatonic).